# Redshift users unable to assume role for external schema based on dbgroup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-iam, amazon-redshift-spectrum

### Background

I have a [Spectrum schema referencing a Glue Data Catalog](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-spectrum-external-schemas.html) (`my_spectrum_schema`). The external schema was created with an IAM role (`s3_glue_role`) with `AWSGlueServiceRole` and `AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess` and a trust relationship like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "redshift.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {
        "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
          "sts:ExternalId": [
            "arn:aws:redshift:<region>:<acct>:dbuser:<cluster>/<admin_user>"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The role is attached to the cluster, and `admin_user` is able to query tables in `my_spectrum_schema` both from the AWS Console and also from a local SQL client.

### Issue

I want to allow members of an existing [Redshift group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Groups.html) to query tables in the schema.

Based on syntax I found [here in the AWS docs](http://%20https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonredshift.html#amazonredshift-resources-for-iam-policies), I expected that adding the group `data_group` to the trust policy would allow members of the group to query the data:

```
          "sts:ExternalId": [
            "arn:aws:redshift:<region>:<acct>:dbuser:<cluster>/<admin_user>",
            "arn:aws:redshift:<region>:<acct>:dbgroup:<cluster>/<data_group>"
          ]
```

However, queries under any user in `data_group` throw this error:

```
Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:     Not authorized to get credentials of role arn:aws:iam::<acct>:role/<s3_glue_role>
  code:      30000
  context:   
  query:     0
  location:  xen_aws_credentials_mgr.cpp:402
  process:   padbmaster [pid=6826]
  -----------------------------------------------
```

### Attempted resolutions

I tried dropping and re-creating the schema after the trust policy had been updated: no effect.

I tried changing `dbgroup` to `dbuser` for `data_group`: (predictably) didn't work.

Searched for similar SO issues. [Allow AWS Redshift Cluster DB user group to assume role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66483945/allow-aws-redshift-cluster-db-user-group-to-assume-role) is related but doesn't have any answers.

I added a user from `data_group` explicitly to the trust relationship, which resolved the error and allows the user to query tables in the schema:

```
          "sts:ExternalId": [
            "arn:aws:redshift:<region>:<acct>:dbuser:<cluster>/<admin_user>",
            "arn:aws:redshift:<region>:<acct>:dbgroup:<cluster>/<data_group>",
            "arn:aws:redshift:<region>:<acct>:dbuser:<cluster>/<single_user>"
```

The workaround isn't ideal because it requires me to manage the `data_group` and the trust policy separately. When users and added or removed from the group, the trust policy should reflect that.

### Question

Is there a different way to specify a Redshift group in the trust policy that will behave the way I'm expecting, or is there another approach altogether to accomplish what I'm trying to do that doesn't feel like an anti-pattern?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to using `dbgroup` to allow IAM permissions?